# Slim framework not working as expected using Composer (Class not found)

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

Can you help me? I'm facing a strange issue.
First, I'm downloading this https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth using composer:

```
composer require tuupola/slim-jwt-auth
```

After that, I created a php file called: teste.php:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App;

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "secret" => "teste",
    "callback" => function ($options) use ($app) {
        $app->jwt = $options["decoded"];
    }
]));

$app->get("/user", function () {
    print_r($app->jwt);
});

$app->run();
```

And now, I'm getting this error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Slim\App' not found
```

This does not make sense, since I used the composer correctly

How can I solve that? I spent many hours trying fix this by myself and I failed. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try this `use \Slim\App;`?

Comment: The same error!

Comment: Did you also install Slim framework using composer?

Comment: Did you also run `composer require slim/slim`?

Comment: I did not stop to think about it! Thank you, I did it, but now I'm getting this error: PHP message: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication' not found`

Comment: My composer:
{
    "require": {
        "tuupola/slim-jwt-auth": "^3.3",
        "slim/slim": "^3.12"
    }
}

Comment: The namespace you're using is incorrect. The constructor for the middleware should be `new Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication(...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to actually add the Slim framework to your Composer package. You can do this by running:

```
composer require slim/slim
```

Regarding your other problem, the constructor you're using for the middleware is incorrect. It should be: `new Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication`.

Your complete code should be as follows:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App;

$app->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "secret" => "teste",
    "callback" => function ($options) use ($app) {
        $app->jwt = $options["decoded"];
    }
]));

$app->get("/user", function () {
    print_r($app->jwt);
});

$app->run();
```